# How to use biglm with doMC and foreach

Tags: r, foreach, domc

Is it possible to run biglm in parallel mode?  I tried to use doMC and then embed biglm in foreach loop, but it seems all cores will be working on the same chunk of data at the same time.  How do I parallelize this?

```
library(doMC)
RegisterDoMC(4)

require(ffbase)
sample <- read.table.ffdf(file="sample_output.csv", FUN = "read.csv", na.strings = "")  
library(biglm)
model<-list()
biglmupdate<-function(dataset,start,end) {
 if (start==1) {
    model <<- biglm(a~b+c, data=dataset[start:end,])
 }
 else {
    model <<- update(model,dataset[start:end,])
 }
}

chunks <- floor(dim(sample)[1]/220000)+1
start<-0; end<-0;
foreach (i = 1: chunks) %dopar% { 
    start = end +1; end =ifelse (i == chunks, dim(sample)[1], start+220000); 
    print(paste("chunk ",i," ",start,":",end," started at:", Sys.time()));
    biglmupdate(dataset = sample, start, end);
    print(paste("chunk ",i,"ended at:", Sys.time()));
}
```

Comment: The updating of the QR decomposition is done in the C & fortran code of the biglm package and is currently sequential (see biglm:::update.biglm & biglm:::update.bigqr). You can ask the biglm author to see if he sees a possibility in allowing non-sequential updates of the QR and the sandwich estimator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the `biglm` package, but it doesn't appear that it can be easily executed in parallel since it works by a sequence of updates to the model object.  Loops of this sort are fundamentally sequential.  For example, you cannot parallelize:

```
i <- 0
for (i in 1:10) {
    i <- i + 1
}
```

by having ten different processes each add `1` to `i`.  The loop depends on making sequential updates to `i`.  From what I can see, the same is true of the `biglm` function.

Besides this fundamental problem, I see two other problems with your code: the computation of `start` and `end`, and the way `model` is modified.  As in my example above, you can't compute the value of loop variables based on values from previous iterations when the loop is executed in parallel.  That could be fixed in this case by changing the loop to something like:

```
n <- nrow(sample)
m <- 220000
foreach(start=seq(1,n,by=m), end=seq(m,n,by=m) %dopar% {
    # ...
}
```

The values of `start` and `end` are all precomputed, and so there is no problem executing the loop in parallel.  I suspect that this solves the problem that led to your comment that all the cores were working on the same chunk of data.  Unfortunately, this doesn't address the fundamental problem of executing `biglm` in parallel.

The problem with `model` is that you're trying to update a single *global-like* variable from parallel processes.  When using `foreach`, you should think in terms of returning a value from each iteration of the loop and processing them with a `.combine` function.  Having the body modify a variable outside of the loop almost always fails.

Comment: Thanks, Steve.  I agree with the coding issues you discovered.  I talked with biglm author and he suggested to combine QR matrix from separate processes, which I'm trying to investigate and will report back.

Comment: @user1030532 I am trying to do something similar. Were you able to parallelize the biglm function?